# Why does Python not implement the elif statement on try statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

So let's make a quick example.

```
my_list = [
    {"name": "toto", "value": 3},
    {"name": "foo", "value": 42},
    {"name": "bar", "value": 56}
]

def foo(name):
    try:
        value = next(e["value"] for e in my_list if e["name"] == name)
    except StopIteration:
        print "Uuuh not found."
    else:
        if value % 2:
            print "Odd !"
        else:
            print "Even !"
```

As you can see, the above code works :

```
>>> foo("toto")
Odd !
>>> foo("foo")
Even !
>>> foo("kappa")
Uuuh not found.
```

I was just wondering if there is a particular reason about why we can't use the `elif` statement with the `try` statement like this :

```
try:
    value = next(e["value"] for e in my_list if e["name"] == name)
except StopIteration:
    print "Uuuh not found."
elif value % 2:
    print "Odd !"
else:
    print "Even !"
```

Of course, this would not work because as it is defined in the [try statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try), the `elif` statement is not defined. But why ? Is there a particular reason (like bound / unbound variable) ? Is there any sources about this ?

(Side note: no `elif-statement` tag ?)

Comment: You have no preceding if which is required

Comment: Wait... no ? Because `if` statement would be a new block ?

Comment: @FunkySayu why not add the if statement with in the block of try

Comment: You should use `if` and  move  if/else inside the try. If there is an error the if/else will not be executed, it is is successful it will

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are asking why then that is a question for the python devs, the syntax is clearly defined in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) you linked to.

Apart from that what you are trying to do can obviously all be done inside the try/except. If you use an else it belongs to the try the same as when you use an else with a for loop, I think it makes perfect sense to only use else and not allow `elif`, elif's are there to behave like `switch/case` statements in other languages.

From an old thread on gossamer-threads [Why no 'elif' in try/except?](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/47699) :

> Because it makes no sense?
>
> The except clauses are for handling exceptions, the else 
>   clause is for handling the case when everything worked fine.
>
> Mixing the two makes no sense. In an except clause, there 
>   is no result to test; in an else clause, there is. Is the elif supposed 
>   to execute when there are exceptions, or when there aren't? 
>   If it's simply an extension to the else clause, then I suppose it 
>   doesn't harm anything, but it adds complexity to the language 
>   definition. At this point in my life, I tend to agree with Einstein - 
>   make everything as simple as possible, but no simpler. The last 
>   place (or at least one of the many last places) I want additional 
>   complexity is in exception handling.

You always need at least one if to use an elif,  it is simply invalid syntax without. The only thing that could end up not being defined is `value`, you should  move the logic inside the try/except using if/else:

```
try:
    value = next(e["value"] for e in my_list if e["name"] == name)
    if value % 2:
        print("Odd !")
    else:
        print("Even !")
except StopIteration:
    print("Uuuh not found.")
```

If `value = next...`  errors your  `print("Uuuh not found.")` will be executed, if not your then your if/else will.

You can have multiple elif's but you must start with an if:

```
if something:
  ...
elif something_else:
   ....
elif .....
```

Another option is to use a default value with `next` then use `if/elif/else`, if we get no name matched next will return `None` so we check `if value is not None`, if it is we print `"Uuuh not found."` or else we got a matched name so we go to the elif/else :

```
value = next((e["value"] for e in my_list if e["name"] == name), None)
if value is None:
    print("Uuuh not found.")
elif value % 2:
    print("Odd !")
else:
    print("Even !")
```

Comment: Excellent answer --- though I think that you could replace the word "can" by "should" in the sense that the block between `try` and `except` is precisely where code that doesn't make sense in the exceptional case is supposed to go.

Comment: How does this answer answer the *why...?* part of the question?

Comment: @pts, because an elif must be preceded by an if, it is not valid python syntax.

Comment: But why must it be? (Why have the designers of Python done it this way?) That's in the title of the original question.

Comment: possible side effect if  value == 0

Comment: @ElRuso, no, we are checking for None not a falsey value, the only value that could cause a side effect is if the value was None

Comment: My mistake, surely zero - is even digit

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So the argument is that because no other language has it python shouldn't have it either? But python have features that are rare in other languages, fx indentation sensitivity. Note that only a few languages has `elif` at all - which languages has it and also has exception handling (prerequisites for the question to have any meaning). I don't know any other languges that has those both features so comparing with other languages is no good argument IMHO. Is there a reason why it would be a bad idea to accept `elif` as part of the `try` statement?

Comment: @skyking, It makes no sense to me to at all to use an elif, in the OP's code there is absolutely no need to do what they are trying to do so adding more complexity to the try to enable people to do completely unnecessary things does not seem like a valid reason, always having an if before an elif makes perfect sense to me, having an else with a try/except or a  loop makes perfect sense to me , using an elif does not and obviously the python devs thought the same. There is no one answer to why not unless you ask guido, there are multiple ways to do what the OP wants without needing an elif.

Comment: I disagree on one thing. In the code I purposed, moving the `if value % 2 == 0` from the `else` to the `try` does not impact the code, but in my mind, this `if` block is at his right place. As you said *The except clauses are for handling exceptions, the else clause is for handling the case when everything worked fine.*, and I will add that the `try` clause must underline only the part probably causing the exception. Further treatments would be in the `else` clause, as purposed in my code.

Comment: I'd probably put the quote at the top, or at least higher up. The `else` as part of a `try block` has nothing to do with an if statement.

Comment: My question is all about the *why*, and you answered it partially : I expect a Python dev team advice on this case, if it exists (I didn't find it).

Comment: @FunkySayu, you won't get a definitive answer without asking the devs or guido himself but I would be pretty confident that the answer you get will be very close to the quote as the start of the answer,  using else makes perfect sense to me, using an elif not so much. The gains vs the added complexity would not be worth it.

Comment: Yes i guess you're right. If some day i'm enough motivated to ask the devs, i'll post their answer here. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @FunkySayu, no prob, I look forward to the answer!

Comment: This logic is circular.

Comment: @SandyChapman, I have no idea what that comment means, what is circular?

Comment: This isn't the exact question asked by the OP, but I'm surprised no one mentioned that similar functionality can be acquired by using a ```try```, ```except```, ```finally``` block which can emulate the function of an ```if```, ```elif```, ```else``` block. Although clearly not intended for OP's desired use case, this can accomplish close to what the OP intended with their: ```try```, ```except```, ```elif``` logic.

Comment: I think the contents of the `try` ought to be limited to what you expect to error, so I wouldn't put the `if-else` inside there.  Instead, put it inside the `else` of the `try-except-else`.

Comment: Isn't `elif` just a short way to write `else if`? Then I still don't understand why it is an allowed short form in some cases and "doesn't make sense" in others. The `if` in `elif` doesn't refer to a previous `if` or "test", it is just a new `if` namely the one in `else if`. The argument that we need an `if` to have an `elif` holds just the same for `else` (where we don't need it, an `except` is good enough).