# elif for except ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Why does this code not work? No easy way to explain.

```
def main():
  while True:
    mon = input("What is the month? ( 1 - 12 )")
    try:
        mon = int(mon)
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again.")
    elif mon > 0 and mon < 13:
        break
    else:
        print("Try again.")
```

Comment: Please at least try to explain - there is no easy way to understand your question. What happens, and what do you expect should have happened? Also, as posted your indentation will produce a syntax error, so please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Python not implement the elif statement on try statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115375/why-does-python-not-implement-the-elif-statement-on-try-statement)

Comment: Did one of the solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes you should make to your code for it to work.

You should use `else` as part of a `try` / `except` / `else` structure. Also use `continue` to signify explicitly where a loop will continue.

Your code is invalid as an `if` / `else` clause cannot start with `elif`.

Here is a working example:

```
def main():
    while True:
        mon = input("What is the month? ( 1 - 12 )")
        try:
            mon = int(mon)
        except ValueError:
            print("Try again.")
            continue
        if mon > 0 and mon < 13:
            break
        else:
            print("Try again.")
    return mon
```

Comment: You don't need the `continue` in the `except` block if you're going to put an `else` afterwards (you only need one of those things, not both). And you don't need the continue at the end of the inner `else` at all, since the end of the loop happens immediately afterwards already.

Comment: @Blckknght, You're right, it's not required. I'm not sure what the style guides say, but [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/9209546) `continue` seems used even when unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's just my personal style then, that I'd never use a redundant `continue`. I would probably use the first `continue` in your code instead of the `else`, but never the completely pointless one at the end.

Comment: @Blckknght, Agreed, that does make sense.